# Preload not working/compiled correctly in production (Electron-vue SimulatedGREG)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, electron, electron-vue

I have a `preload` script that is working well in development. I've seen [here](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/239) that I either need to use a `static` file or `webpack`. I went  with the `static` approach because my knowledge is zero with the `webpack` one.

Currently, I'm using a webview, and this webview has the `preload` as following:

```
<webview :id="webview.key" :src="webview.url" :preload="preload_path" style="height: 100%" pcontextIsolation></webview>
```

the `preload_path` is as following:

```
preload_path: `file://${path.join(__static, '/serverBrowserIPC.js')}`,
```

my project's structure is:

```
- dist
- - static 
    serverBrowserIPC.js 
    api.js
- src 
- - main 
- - renderer
```

the `preload` file is `serverBrowserIPC.js`, and `serverBrowserIPC.js` requires `api.js`

```
require("./api.js")
```

For known reasons that I'm not aware of, the `preload` is not working and it's throwing the following error:

```
F:\Web\my-project\build\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\dist\electron\static\serverBrowserIPC.js
```

For me, it doesn't make sense, because I have already stated it's in a static folder, but the `electron-app` is deciding to access it through the bundled `app.asar`.

I hope someone helps me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems the issue is that your project structure is slightly wrong. The static directory is supposed to be located in the project root directory. When you build your app for production that directory will get copied into the app.asar directory. That's why its looking there. But, since there is no static directory in the root directory nothing gets copied over.

To check the project directory structure check the following documentation page:
https://webpack.electron.build/project-structure

Comment: It's really weird that I just figured that I put it in the wrong `static` folder :D . Thank you for your detailed answer! I marked it as the correct one.

Comment: I'm glad i could help :-)